# Angular requisition http method Get

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I have a problem with an http request via the post method.
When then send to the back end that has an endpoint mapped as

My CarController

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/car")
@AllArgsConstructor
@CrossOrigin
public class CarController {

@PostMapping(value = "/test/{code}")
    public ResponseEntity<String> getCars(@PathVariable(required = true) String code) throws URISyntaxException {
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Response OK");
    }
}
```

My environment

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  apiEndpoint: "http://localhost:8080/my-app/"
};
```

My app.service.component.ts

```
httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }),
  };

getCars() {
    const url = `${environment.apiEndpoint}`+ "/car/teste/?" + `${code}`;
    this.http.get<any>(url).subscribe(resp => {
    console.log(resp)
   });
}
```

Error log

The request has a 404 error with the following message

> ERROR {body: {…}, url: 'http://localhost:8080/car/test/', headers:
> HttpHeaders, status: 404, statusText: 'Not Found'}body: {error:
> "Collection 'car' not found"}headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames:
> Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}status: 404statusText: "Not
> Found"url: "http://localhost:8080/my-app/car/test"[[Prototype]]:
> Object

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you mean making a `get` request, since the methods above are `get` requests.

Anyway, double check your URL spellings, for in the API endpoint, the URL is `/test/{code}`, yet in the client, the URL is `".../teste/?"...`

The `e` in `teste` may be causing the 404

Comment: My url angular:
  const url = `${environment.apiEndpoint}`+ "/test/" + `${code}`;

Answer (score 0):

You're passing the code param as a Query param, not like a param of the route. That's why it doesn't find the car.

Comment: My endpoint return 
System.out.println("code") and response.OK("Teste")
Don´t call repository...